# How to change the form action of jquery-file-upload?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the [JQuery-File-Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and I have tried changing the action attribute to my specific one but it has no effect I still get a POST request with `upload` instead of the intended value `portfolio/upload/do`:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/portfolio/upload/do" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Is this the correct way to change the action url name or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change **`data-url` attribute** of fileupload input instead of changing form action.

**And you even dont need form tag itself.**

Plugin that you are using is **actually wraps your input with the form** and it use data attributes of your input to set action and other params.

[Here is an example of basic usage.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin)